# Automate deployment of XMLA / documentation on Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla

Tags: powershell, ssas, xmla

I'm looking to automate the deployment of XMLA scripts. I've come across [an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20201204084443/http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2006/06/14/powershellandxmla.aspx) that gives a small demo, but I'm hoping to find more info.

Specifically, where is the documentation for `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient` and what is the best approach for overridding the database and connection values that are embedded in the XMLA script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient is an undocumented library that is actually part of Management Studio and is not re-distributable. I think that using one of Jason's suggestions or the AMO library are your only approaches.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are just trying to deploy the analysis service cube. This utility has commandline switches and can suport configuration for different targets
[Analysis Services Deployment Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162758.aspx)

If you need to add further customizations, you can always process the resulting xml files with either xslt, powershell, or .net

ascmd.exe can also run xmla scripts:
[ascmd.exe commandlline utility](http://msftasprodsamples.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SS2005%21Readme%20For%20Command-line%20Utility%20Sample)